# how can i get the return value from modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, return

I plan to make a custom confirm window,and I try to catch the value(true or false) when user click, but the function return "" before the click event,how can i get the return value(true or false) after user clicks?

code is as blow:

```
function getval(){
$("body").click(function(){
    return 1;
});
}

a=getval();
```

how can a get the value "1" from getval() when "body" is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Why you bind click events on events? These binds wont execute. You cand use `$(document).delegate("selector", "event", function(){})` to bind them to the window so if you create or destroy the popup, they will always run. I cant ensure those values still return the desired value, since you are declaring that outside the click function and using inside it.

Comment: thanks Diego,i tested it,i bind them to the document  but every time i run the function returns immediately.it seems that browser wont  wait for click event ,it returns immedately ,then if click event happends,it return.but it doesn't return to the same variable any more!

Comment: inside the click event you can check which element has been pressed:

`$("body").click(function(e){
    var elem = $(e.target) // jQuery reference object to element clicked
    return elem.is("desired-target");
})`

Answer (score 0):

I answer the one where return value is 1.

=END VALUE(,-1,-33455.76)+-1*-33455.76

This is a copy of my formula in ExCeL, and i Get In the answer Window = $0.00 with means 2*50%=100% that means 33455.76x2=100% and the return value is 1 out of 2 that means $33455.76 if dollar is the curransy your after.

Answer (score -1):

$(dokument)delegate(«selektert»,»event,funktion(-1*-$35000=35000){thus if @}
$(«body»).click(funktion(e){1transaktions$35000){thus if previus event did not accure go back to thus like nothing was don.   Var element=$(e).target)//jQuery reference object to element clicked return element.is(desired-target»);})